# Gradle "offline work" removed from gradle android studio setting

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I use **Android Studio Version 4.0 RC** version, and it seems it removed the **offline work** mode.

[image]

Where can I find this item in the android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the gradle offline mode toggle in the gradle tab on the right side of the Android Studio,[image: Gradle Offline Toggle]

Comment: Yes, that's the new way of making it disabled. If you cannot find on the right side, then go to  View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle

Answer (score 1):

You can activate/deactivate this from Gradle Tab (Top Right) by clicking the icon to **toggle offline mode**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Outside android-studio you can also use **settings.gradle** file:

startParameter.offline=true